# How to add textboxes, labels and buttons dynamically at runtime in VB?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How to create a form with a button `add_subjects` which adds one `textbox` and a corresponding label on each click,`3 buttons - Add, Edit and Delete`, for each `textbox` created during runtime in `VB`. 
Once each `texbox's` corresponding `Add _button` is clicked, it passes `textbox's` value to the label.

Comment: why dont you use datagrid and edit everthing there?

Answer (score 4):

```
Private Property number as Integer=1

Private Sub add_subject_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add_subject.Click
    Dim tb As New TextBox
    tb.Name="TextBox"+number.ToString
    tb.Position = New Point(number*40,10) ' change this if you want
    Me.Controls.Add(tb)
    Dim lb As New Label
    lb.Name="Label"+number.ToString
    lb.Position = New Point(number*40,50) ' change this if you want
    Me.Controls.Add(lb)
    Dim add As New Button
    add.Name="AddButton"+number.ToString
    add.Position = New Point(number*40,100) ' change this if you want
    AddHandler(add.Click, AdressOf(add_Click))
    Me.Controls.Add(add)
    Dim edit As New Button
    edit.Name="EditButton"+number.ToString
    edit.Position = New Point(number*40,150) ' change this if you want
    AddHandler(edit.Click, AdressOf(edit_Click))'you have to make edit_Click
    YourForm.Controls.Add(edit)
    Dim delete As New Button
    delete.Name="DeleteButton"+number.ToString
    delete.Position = New Point(number*40,200) ' change this if you want
    AddHandler(delete.Click, AdressOf(delete_Click))'you have to make delete_Click
    Me.Controls.Add(delete)
    number+=1
End Sub
```

So we make all controls, dynamically make names, change positions, add handlers and add controls to form.

```
Private Sub add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Ctype(Me.Controls.Find("Label"+sender.Name.Substring(9),True).First,Label).Text = Ctype(Me.Controls.Find("TextBox"+sender.Name.Substring(9),True).First,TextBox).Text 
End Sub
```

Here we find Label And TextBox using sender's number(sender.Name.Substring(9) will remove AddButton and leave number) and change Label.Text to TextBox.Text.

Get all label values and insert them in database:

```
Private Sub save(sender As Object, e as EventArgs) Handles button_save_subjects.Click
For i = 1 to number
    Dim value As String
    value = CType(Me.Controls.Find("Label"+number.ToString).First,Label).Text
    'insert into database
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to track each of these dynamically created labels and their values, so that I can store those labels values as a table fields in a database using SQL embedded in a button_save_subjects event?

Comment: I added code to get all values,but I don't know SQL so you'll have to insert values in database.

Answer (score 3):

A control like a textbox is just an object of the class Textbox. In order for the form to display this object it needs to be added to the form's Controls property. To create a new textbox all you need to do is

```
Dim newTB as New Textbox
newTB.Name = "tbNew"
'Set location, size and so on if you like
Me.Controls.Add(newTB)
```

If you want your control to be able to respond to events you need to add an event handler for the event you want to the control. This handler refers the event to a method of your choice.

```
Public Class Form1

  Sub CreateTB
    Dim NewTB as New Textbox
    newTB = New Textbox
    newTB.Name = "tbNew"
    AddHandler newTB.TextChanged, AddressOf HandleTextChanged
    Me.Controls.Add(newTB)
  End Sub


  Private Sub HandleTextChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    'Handle the event
  End Sub
End Class
```

You should make sure that the names are unique if you are creating the controls or you might run into trouble.

You can also store your created controls in an array or list as a global variable. That way you can easily access them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

**Create dynamic Textbox]**

```
Private Sub btnCreateTextbox_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreateTextbox.Click
        Dim textbox1 As New TextBox
        textbox1.Name = "Textbox1"
        textbox1.Size = New Size(170, 20)
        textbox1.Location = New Point(167, 32)
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(textbox1)
  End Sub
```

**Create Dynamic Label]**

```
Private Sub lblCreateLabel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblCreateLabel.Click
    Dim label1 As New Label
    label1.Name = "label1"
    label1.Text = "Enter Name"
    label1.AutoSize = True
    label1.Location = New Point(80, 33)
    GroupBox1.Controls.Add(label1)
End Sub
```

[Refer Here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Dynamic-TextBox-Label-and-Button-controls-with-TextChanged-and-Click-event-handlers-in-Windows-Forms-WinForms-Application.aspx)

[Source](http://www.authorcode.com/create-dynamic-textbox-and-label-in-vb-net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code as above and, in the end, use the parent property of control.
Because the control (TextBox, Buttom, etc.) is "inside" of a "container" (form, groupbox, etc.). Like this...

```
  ...
  Dim textbox1 As New TextBox
  textbox1.Name = "Textbox1" 'or other
  ...
  textbox1.parent = Me 'Me = the form
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Call AddTextBox()
End Sub

Sub AddTextBox()

    Dim i As Integer = 1

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            i = i + 1
            'MsgBox(i)
        End If
    Next ctrl

    Dim Label As New Label
    Label.Name = "Label" & i
    Label.Size = New Size(170, 20)
    Label.Location = New Point(200, (20 + (i * 55)))
    Label.Text = "Lbl" & i

    Dim Textbox As New TextBox
    Textbox.Name = "Textbox" & i
    Textbox.Size = New Size(170, 20)
    Textbox.Location = New Point(200, (38 + (i * 55)))
    Me.Controls.Add(Label)
    Me.Controls.Add(Textbox)


End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some context to your answer so that others can understand exactly why you suggest this solution?