# Dynamically Add Textbox to TableCell

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add a Textbox to a new table cell when clicking a button. I have tried following the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991539/how-to-add-textboxes-labels-and-buttons-dynamically-at-runtime-in-vb), but I am not able to add the Textbox to the table cell controls. Specifically, I am getting "Value of type 'Textbox' cannot be converted to 'Control'". Any help would be appreciated.

```
Protected Sub addRow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim tbox As New TextBox
    tbox.Name = "TextBox " + 1
    Dim tCell As New TableCell()
    tCell.Controls.Add(tbox)            'ERROR OCCURS HERE

    Dim trow As New TableRow()
    supply_log.Controls.Add(trow)
    trow.Controls.Add(tCell)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting it as a control:

```
 tCell.Controls.Add(CType(tbox,Control))
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but when I try that, I get the error: "Value of type 'Control' cannot be converted to 'Control'".

Comment: What is the full type of the textbox? It should be system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox If it's a webform you are working on

Comment: Ah that did it. I was using System.Windows.Forms.Textbox. Thanks!